# MATLAB - Obtaining Nested Table as List

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, nested, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert a MATLAB table into a CSV file, but cannot seem to do it because it contains many nested tables. For inner tables of less than 10 entries it seems to appear as below, which is fine for copying to a CSV file/Excel spreadsheet.

```
[61964943979.0000;61964979139.0000;45452867286.0000;61965359883.0000;46605573591.0000;61965019959.0000;61964944035.0000;962127853874.000;61964943984.0000]
```

However inner tables greater than 10 appear as below, which causes issues.

```
12x1 double
```

How can I copy the full table with inner tables in the first format, or write this out to a CSV file with all inner tables expanded? Thank you.

Comment: What code do you use to do the conversion? Do you have an example of your nested table? What error did MATLAB throw? Or in what way it failed to complete the conversion?

Comment: @Anthony I don't know how to convert it. I have use the copy to Excel GUI option.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of the "nested tables"?